# TL2011 installation keeps failing due to error

Tags: errors, installing, texlive

```
Installing [0960/2311, time/total: 22:33/56:42]: hfoldsty [598k]
Installing [0961/2311, time/total: 22:39/56:53]: hhtensor [167k]
Installing [0962/2311, time/total: 22:43/57:02]: histogr [95k]
./tlpkg/installer/xz/xzdec.x86_64-linux: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
untar: untarring /home/peter/texlive/2011/temp/histogr.source.tar failed (in /home/peter/texlive/2011/texmf-dist)
untarring /home/peter/texlive/2011/temp/histogr.source.tar failed, stopping install.
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
Writing log file to current working directory.
```

Why is this happening?  I can I proceed?  Debian 6 64 bit, `~/home/peter/texlive/2011/` is where the installation has been directed to.

Comment: Did you try again without the cache from previous attempts?

Comment: @Raphink Without the cache?  What does this mean?  How do I do this?

Comment: When the installation fails and you restart it, it asks you if you wan to use the cache of the previously failed installation. Try saying no.

Comment: Ok will try.  Can you explain why doing this helps?

Comment: The error suggests that one of the archives is probably corrupted. Re-installing without the cache will download the archives again and thus get rid of the faulty archive. Another solution would be to just remove the faulty archive from the temporary directory before restarting the installation.

Comment: I actually accidentally pressed y again and it noticed that it progressed.  Each time it progressed to a more advanced stage of the installation, so if you are persistent eventually the job will get done.  A bit annoying though!  :P

Comment: I had similar issues with a pretty much error prone hard drive. I kept relaunching until it installed completely. That was indeed annoying though.

Comment: @Raphink: Please convert your comments into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar case happened to me, on a machine with a bad drive (in my case, a bad NFS mount) yielding many r/w errors.

I eventually managed to install TL2011 by simply restarting the install over and over, choosing to use the cache every time, so it wouldn't download the files a second time. Each time, it progressed a little bit, until finally it had downloaded everything and proceeded with the installation.

Another solution would be to get it to download the files in another directory (or on another computer, and use a removable device). I haven't found an option for that though.